# Why am I getting a format exception in this C# code?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, parsing, exception

I am working on a Windows Form application. I am parsing an XML file and doing some queries. For example, in this case I am trying to find all users weighing between 55 and 100. For some reason, when I run this code, I get a format exception unhandled. Why am I getting a format exception. I have indicated the breakpoint where the exception occurs. I think the problem is a syntactical error. 
Thanks for your help.

```
private bool UserWeighsBetween55and100(IEnumerable<XElement> paramsList) {
    bool result = false;
    foreach (XElement parameter in paramsList) {
        if (parameter.Attribute("name").Value == "Weight") {
  --->HERE     if ((Int32.Parse(parameter.Attribute("value").Value) > 55) &&
                   (Int32.Parse(parameter.Attribute("value").Value) < 100)){
                        return true;
                   }
               }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What is type of `parameter.Attribute("value").Value` exactly and what is it's value? And what is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: It is a string, for example "110"

Comment: if the problem is syntactical then the program wouldn't compile

Comment: Most probably you are missing some values in xml file. Try to debug every value and check .

Comment: [Int32.Parse MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) => `FormatException:` s is **not in the correct format.**

Comment: @Ralphyabro With `foreach (var culture in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures))`, none of culture throws exception with `Int32.TryParse("110", culture)`

Comment: Could it be that I cannot compare two Int32 data types with the use of '>' and '<' operators?

Comment: @Ralphyabro You can compare integers with `<` or `>` operators. That's not the case.

Comment: I think I caught the problem, I don't have only Int's that are being parsed, there are also doubles!! This explains the format exception!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will be answering my question because I found out my mistake and I hope it would help everybody reading this post.

The problem with using `Int32.Parse()` was that while I was parsing the XML file, I didn't pay attention to the values of type `double`.
The fix for this code would be as follows:

```
private bool UserWeighsBetween55and100(IEnumerable<XElement> paramsList) {
        bool result = false;
        foreach (XElement parameter in paramsList) {
            if (parameter.Attribute("name").Value == "Weight") {
                if ((parameter.Attribute("value").Value)!=null) {
                    if ((Convert.ToDouble(parameter.Attribute("value").Value) > 55) && (Convert.ToDouble(parameter.Attribute("value").Value) < 100)) {
                    return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert your value once instead of converting same value two time.

Try to do like this.

```
int iValue = 0;
if (Int.TryParse(parameter.Attribute("value").Value, out iValue)) //If the value converted
{
    if (iValue > 55 && iValue < 100)
    {
        return true;
    }

}
else //Failed to convert value into int datatype
{
    //Code here if conversion faild
}
```

if the `parameter.Attribute("value").Value` is containing non-numeric value then it wont convert in `int` datatype.

Comment: That's not the point. If `Int.Parse` throws exception, `Int.TryParse` also returns `false` for same situation.

Comment: at-least you can handle the error if the value is not converted. as i have mentioned that if the value is containing non-numeric value then it will fail. how you can handle that value in else condition.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the "Parse" method, use the tryParse.

In your case, it would look like :

```
foreach (XElement parameter in paramsList) {
    if (parameter.Attribute("name").Value == "Weight") {
    int value;
    if(!Int32.TryParse(parameter.Attribute("value").Value, out value)){
         //Not a number, handle this case
    }
    if ((value > 55) &&  (value < 100)){
        return true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your second if statement works no matter `Int32.TryParse` returns `true` or `false`.

Comment: That's why you should handle the case if the TryParse fail, with continue, exception, or whatever he may want to do.